# Laravel PUT request parameter

Tags: laravel

When the route is:

```
  Route::post('/abcd',...);
```

Then in controller I get the parameter like this:

```
   $r->get('param')   // with Request $r
```

But while the route is of a `PUT` request type:

```
   Route::put('/abcd,...);
```

That code doesn't work. It doesn't get the value of parameter.

Comment: what do you want to achive?

Comment: I use postman to test. Method is PUT with parameter 'status' = 1. In server side, I can get the parameter.

Comment: -- Kindly add your code sample so we can figure out the issue, you can access parameters in same way in both put and post.

-- Make sure you are not using HTML form to post on this route as HTML forms do not support PUT, PATCH or DELETE actions.

-- Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#form-method-spoofing

Comment: thank you all, postman request with Put parameter then laravel can not get it. But real code (android) requests I can receive it. This issue is Postman

Answer (score 37):

Try setting x-www-form-urlencoded for body in the postman.

Comment: What if we have file field for updating the user profile image as an example.

Answer (score 15):

Set method to POST and add _method field with PUT value[image]

Comment: only wasted half a day on this #efficiency

Answer (score 3):

Route:

```
$api->put('photos', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\PhotoController@updatePhoto');
```

Controller code:

```
public function updatePhoto(Request $request)
{
    $paramValue = $request->get('param_name');
}
```

Working fine for me.

Comment: thanks! It work with android testing. Postman testing can not request put parameter . Sorry I dont have enough point to vote you.

Comment: @SangTrần Postman has a separate put method to test put requests, we are using it successfully. By the way I have added this answer to help you not for the vote :)

Comment: thanks you. I can test get and post method. but using put, input::all() return null

Comment: Instead of input::all() use $request->all()

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

Just added an extra field in form.
works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

If submitting an API request and you don't want your developers to send a `POST` request with `_method=PUT` request variable, see solution here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13457#issuecomment-341973180