# 1048 Column &#039;firstname&#039; cannot be null ERROR in postman from laravel backend

Tags: php, laravel, postman

So i'm trying to update my user via postman, but with no luck. I keep getting the same error and I have no idea what is going wrong.

I use laravel sanctum for my login/register.

ProfileController.php

```
    public function updateProfile(Request $request)
    {
        
    $user = $request->user();
    
    $user->update([
        'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'), 
        'email' => $request->input('email'), 
    ]);
        
    }
```

UserModel

```
protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'role',
        'password',
    ];
```

Api.php

```
Route::group(["namespace"=>"Api"],function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
        Route::put('/update-profile', [ProfileController::class, 'updateProfile']);
    });
});
```

Postman is: PUT + http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update-profile on BODY form-data with firstname as key and a random value. (see image)

Really hope someone can help me since it's probably an easy fix. Let me know if you need any additional code. [image]

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Based on title I'd say you're not passing firstname parameter in request, make sure you have correct key. Otherwise check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863204/laravel-put-request-parameter

Comment: Can share screen shot for api postman, that what are you passing in firstname and email

Comment: @StewieSWS 1048 Column &#039;firstname&#039; cannot be null is my error. You can check the image for clarification of the key (which is correct)

Comment: Also @Ali image in post !

Comment: @Vyrn send it as a POST request and add the input "_method" with value "PUT" to the form. it's an issue with PUT method not having a body by standards

Comment: @N69S It works thankfully! Is there anyway to counter this though? Cause it would just be weird code if I want to connect this with my frontend.

Basically is this only an issue in postman and will this just work without having to send _method whenever I for example update via frontend inputs?

Comment: @Vyrn depends on what you use to send the request, jquery's ajax for example wont work but react will. so try it and if it doesnt work you know how to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

I have update the route method type to 'PUT'

```
 Route::group(["namespace" => "Api"], function () {
   Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum'], function () {
    Route::put('update-profile', [ProfileController::class, 'updateProfile']);
    });
 });
```

make sure you call save() function after update

```
 $user->update([
        'firstname' => $request->input('firstname'),
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
    ]);
  $user->save();
```

Comment: "_make sure you call save() function after update_" That's not necessary

Comment: Still now working for me. I've added a screenshot from postman.

Comment: Also I put the wrong route lol, I didnt have put. I've updated the post again :)