UpdateForm.js:78 PUT http://localhost:8080/api/items/4 422 (Unprocessable Content)
I was working on a Small Personal Project of mine of learning purposes.
Using ReactJs as Frontend & send requests to Laravel API as Backend.
The CRUD application I made is almost complete but the update operation is not working as intended.
I tried many things but made things nothing but worse.
Here is my UpdateForm.js Code:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, Navigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Details from "./Details";

const UpdateForm = ({ apiUrl, storageLink }) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);
  const [item, setItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    price: "",
    quantity: "",
    image: null,
  });
  const [oldItem, setOldItem] = useState({
    name: "",
    price: "",
    quantity: "",
    image: "",
  });
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItem(id);
  }, [id]);

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}/${id}`);
      const itemData = response.data;
      setItem({
        name: itemData.name,
        price: itemData.price,
        quantity: itemData.quantity,
        image: itemData.image,
      });
      setOldItem({
        name: itemData.name,
        price: itemData.price,
        quantity: itemData.quantity,
        image: itemData.image,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching item:", error);
    }
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    if (!item.name) return "Name field is required.";
    if (!item.price || isNaN(item.price)) return "Valid price is required.";
    if (!item.quantity || isNaN(item.quantity)) return "Valid quantity is required.";
    return null;
  };

  const handleUpdate = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formError = validateForm();
    if (formError) {
      setError(formError);
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", item.name);
    formData.append("price", item.price);
    formData.append("quantity", item.quantity);
    if (item.image instanceof File) {
      formData.append("image", item.image);
    }

    for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.put(`${apiUrl}/${id}`, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      console.log("Item updated:", response.data);
      setIsUpdated(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Could not update item:", error);
      setError(error.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred");
    }
  };

  if (isUpdated) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="row m-5">
      <div className="col-md-8">
        <div className="card p-3 shadow-lg">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
              <h1 className="display-1">Update Item</h1>
              <hr />
            </div>
          </div>
          {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
          <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <label htmlFor="itemName" className="form-text text-start">
                  Name
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => setItem({ ...item, name: e.target.value })}
                  className="form-control"
                  value={item.name}
                  name="itemName"
                  id="itemName"
                  type="text"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <label htmlFor="itemPrice" className="form-text text-start">
                  Price
                </label>
                <div className="input-group">
                  <span className="input-group-text">$</span>
                  <input
                    onChange={(e) => setItem({ ...item, price: e.target.value })}
                    value={item.price}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="itemPrice"
                    id="itemPrice"
                    type="number"
                    step="0.01"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <label htmlFor="itemQuantity" className="form-text text-start">
                  Quantity
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => setItem({ ...item, quantity: e.target.value })}
                  value={item.quantity}
                  className="form-control"
                  name="itemQuantity"
                  id="itemQuantity"
                  type="number"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col">
                <label htmlFor="itemImage" className="form-text text-start">
                  Select Image
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => setItem({ ...item, image: e.target.files[0] })}
                  className="form-control"
                  name="itemImage"
                  id="itemImage"
                  type="file"
                />
                <p className="form-text fst-italic" style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>
                  Only following file types supported: JPG, JPEG, PNG, PNEG, GIF, SVG. <br />
                  <strong>File size must not exceed 5MB</strong>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row mb-2">
              <div className="col-auto text-start">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                  Update Item
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="col-auto">
                <Link to="/" className="btn btn-outline-light">
                  Cancel
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <div className="card p-3 shadow-lg">
          <Details
            text="Previous Details"
            itemName={oldItem.name}
            itemPrice={oldItem.price}
            itemQuantity={oldItem.quantity}
            itemImage={oldItem.image}
            storageLink={storageLink}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UpdateForm;

Here is my Update function in my Backend ItemController.php:
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            "name"=>"required|string|max:255",
            "price"=>"required|numeric",
            "quantity"=>"required|integer",
            "image"=>"nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,pneg,gif,svg|max:5120",
        ]);

        $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            // Delete the old image if it exists
            if ($item->image) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($item->image);
            }

            $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
            $validatedData['image'] = $imagePath;
        }

        $item->update($validatedData);
        return response()->json($item, 200);
    }

It is acting as if all the fields of the form being sent are empty when they are clearly not.

I tried logging out Form Data, Tried removing restrictions from the backend function even though they are necessary. Once removed, the form is submitted but no data is updated.
I dont know how the data is not being processed correctly by the server, when i am using the same methods to perform add operations [axios.post instead of axios.put ofcourse] and it works fine.
same appending of formdata variable.
Please Help.

Hi, please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.  This is too long.
Also, a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

What @pierpy wrote and thinking: That depends if the PHP application is configured for PUT or not. PUT (often) requires additional configuration as PHP only knows POST and GET, and GET normally is not a problem as it's within the URL and always on, however for PUT the PHP SAPI won't setup the POST vars. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863204/laravel-put-request-parameter and https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/requests#retrieving-the-request-method etc. I'd learn about the request object first, this is one central point you'd like to have covered.

I used php artisan install:api command to create the api.php route file in the routes folder. That file has the code: `<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ItemController;
Route::apiResource('items', ItemController::class);` How do i control the type of request?

This question is similar to: Laravel $request->all() is empty using multipart/form-data. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is a well known issue when using form-data with PUT. The easiest way would be to send a POST request from react and add formData.append('_method', 'PUT') or set the X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE header with value PUT to spoof the method, Laravel will treat it as a PUT request.

Oh my god...thanks alot bro Arun A S...
i don't know how to add it to the accepted Answer but if you can please do so.
it fixed my application and now it works perfectly fine.
Thanks once again.
I added the formData.append("_method","PUT"); to the formData variable code and then tried updating a record and it works like a charm. <3
*i was stuck on this for almost a week
